# Symfony3: download files in php google api v3 instead of v2

Tags: symfony, google-api-php-client

Previously I had the following code to download a pdf through the google api (v2)

```
public function downloadRoomAvailabilityAction()
{
    $config = $this->container->getParameter( 'happy_r_google_api' );
    $client = new GoogleClient($config);
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client->getGoogleClient());

    $file = $service->files->get('1iSAIgAsNjqqvzh05Pk4hos95VSgBW7JgLb1C3x_jA2M');

    $downloadUrl = $file->getExportLinks();

    if ($downloadUrl) {
        $request = new \Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl['application/pdf'], 'GET', null, null);

        $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
        if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {

            $content = $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
            $response = new Response();

            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.'room_availability.pdf'.'"');

            $response->setContent($content);
            return $response;
        } else {
            // An error occurred.
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
        return null;
    }
}
```

but in v3 this is not working anymore. as it gives me the following error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getExportLinks" of class "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile".
```

from the docs the example is given:

```
$fileId = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo';
$content = $driveService->files->export($fileId, 'application/pdf', array('alt' => 'media' ));
```

but i am not sure how to modify my existing code to make it work with v3. can anyone give a suggestion?
I am using happy_r google api bundle for symfony, though if there is a way to do it without it, that is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try this

```
public function downloadRoomAvailabilityAction()
{
    $config = $this->container->getParameter( 'happy_r_google_api' );
    $client = new GoogleClient($config);
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client->getGoogleClient());

    $fileId = '1iSAIgAsNjqqvzh05Pk4hos95VSgBW7JgLb1C3x_jA2M';
    $content = $service->files->export($fileId, 'application/pdf', array('alt' => 'media' ));

    if ($content) {            
        $response = new Response();

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.'room_availability.pdf'.'"');

        $response->setContent($content);
        return $response;        
    } else {
        // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me. i am getting the following response: {
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "internalError",
"message": "Internal Error"
}
],
"code": 500,
"message": "Internal Error"
}
}